# Change value of label element inserting href inside

Tags: javascript, html

I have this element:

```
<li class="choice-1 depth-1"><input type="checkbox" id="wpforms-1028-field_3_1" name="wpforms[fields][3][]" value="Acepto la política de privacidad" required ><label class="wpforms-field-label-inline" for="wpforms-1028-field_3_1">Acepto la política de privacidad</label></li>
```

I want to change this text: `Acepto la política de privacidad`

to this: `Acepto la <a href='https://XXXX/gdpr/'>política de privacidad TEST</a>`

I have tried this code:

`document.getElementById("wpforms-1028-field_3_1").value="Acepto la <a href='https://XXXX/gdpr/'>política de privacidad TEST</a>"`

But it doesn't work because it seem I am not inside the "label" element.

Comment: You seem to have a good identifier for the label, `for` attribute. Use that as an attribute selector to refer to the element to change: `document.querySelector('[for="wpforms-1028-field_3_1"]').innerHTML = '...';`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that you use **getElementById** and added a class name to search for. **getElementById** function searches for data inside the ID attribute:

```
<div id="TO FIND"></div>
```

**Replace code using element ID**

If you want to use the ID element you can do this with the following code:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "your HTML code";
```

I have added a example below with a button, if you click it your requested change will be added.

```js
function test() {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Acepto la <a href='https://XXXX/gdpr/'>política de privacidad TEST</a>";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="choice-1 depth-1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="wpforms-1028-field_3_1" name="wpforms[fields][3][]" value="Acepto la política de privacidad" required>
  <label id="test" class="wpforms-field-label-inline" for="wpforms-1028-field_3_1">Acepto la política de privacidad</label></li>

<button onClick="test();">Click me to change</button>
```

**Replace code using element CLASS NAME**

To make the changes by search on class name you have to use following code

```
    document.getElementsByClassName("wpforms-field-label-inline")[0].innerHTML = "Acepto la <a href='https://XXXX/gdpr/'>política de privacidad TEST</a>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use document query selector

```
document.querySelector(".wpforms-field-label-inline").innerHTML = "cepto la <a href='https://XXXX/gdpr/'>política de privacidad TEST</a>";
```

Comment: Il up vote your comment but change your example to the class name he uses. Also you have a typo "p.example" will not work. You have to use ".example". Working example: "document.querySelector(".wpforms-field-label-inline").innerHTML = "Value, what you want";"

Comment: Thanks for the upvote and to catch my typo mistakes.